# Why String.contains() can not accept a regex as a parameter?

Tags: java

Any idea to Implementing this?

Is this best way to do?

```
boolean contains=string.split(regex,2).length==2;
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: Because it doesn't. The question should be addressed to the author of the API. All you will get here is guesswork. Not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd usually use something like:

```
boolean contains = pattern.matcher(text).find();
```

where `pattern` is an instance of `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

Comment: thanks for answer,every time `Pattern.compile(...)`(or cache it) is better than `string.split(regex,2)`?

Comment: @Zenofo if you check the code of split(String regex), you find compile(regex) too.

Comment: @Zenofo: I'd cache it - typically you'll want the same pattern throughout. I'd say it's better than using `split` because it's a *lot* clearer what it's trying to do: find a match for the regular expression within the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily implemented in terms of `Matcher.find()`:

```
public static boolean containsRegex(String input, String regex) {
  return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).find();
}
```

However, it is rarely necessary as you can simply stay with `matches`, slightly expanding your regex to begin and end with `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
boolean contains = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).find();
```